# Is there an Excel viewer for Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, microsoft-excel

Is there an Excel viewer for Mac OS X?  I understand that the OS X developer tools are free and the Excel format is documented and I can teach myself Objective C on the web and set "write Excel viewer" as my first assignment, but I am hoping for a solution with a lower activation energy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Though not perfect: in Finder simply press the Spacebar to activate Quick Look, which offers a read-only view [of many file formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Look#Supported_file_types_by_default) without requiring to have the file's application installed.

Comment: Do you need to have Numbers installed for this to work? I ask because quicklook & preview do not work for me.

Comment: Nope, @xer0x, I don't have Numbers installed. Works just fine. Maybe it's just a specific document that doesn't work for you?

Comment: shop not available :(

Comment: Or right-click Finder context menu on the `.xlsx` file and pick "Quick Look" --this pops up a persistent window. Picking another file in same folder (mouse or keyboard) displays it in the Quick Look window.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [Office Web Apps](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps/) instead, which also allows you to edit files.  You just need a [Microsoft Account](https://account.microsoft.com/) (you can use any email address to make one, I think).  Just pop the Excel file in your OneDrive space and open it from there.

Here's an [example file](http://goo.gl/FmDl) that I have publicly shared.

Answer (score 4):

Numbers (from iWork) s capable of opening .xls and .xlsx files.

Answer (score 2):

OS X 10.7.4 opens up Excel documents in Preview without the need for other software. Obviously you can't edit it but it's fine for viewing.

Answer (score 1):

OpenOffice or NeoOffice (the Native MacOS X port of OpenOffice) can read/write all MS Office files, including Excel files, and much more.

Answer (score 0):

> I can teach myself Objective C on the
>   web and set "write Excel viewer" as my
>   first assignment ...

As already stated in other answers, you can use Apple's "Numbers" to open Excel files, but creating or modifying Excel files programatically is a different story; you *might* need to have the appropriate tools (SDKs etc.) installed to do that. May I ask what tutorial you're following?

If the guide has prerequisites, it should specify how to meet them. (Depending on what exactly you want to accomplish, this *might* actually be a question better asked on StackOverflow).

Comment: Step zero would be to write the tutorial, but the one I could write prior to learning Objective C would likely suffer from quality of implementation issues.

Comment: @Thomas: Oooh, my apologies! I misunderstood part of your question - my bad! I thought you were following a tutorial. I'm glad you found a solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wish to view the excel data, quicklook in Mac seems to be better option.  As given above, right click on the file in the 'Finder' and try QuickLook, s given above.

Comment: Welcome to superuser: Please read the question and the other answers again carefully. Your answer is almost the same as the accepted answer, Please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou